the existence of solution satisfying a ddbar equation
Denote by $\mathbb D$ (resp. $\mathbb D^*$) the open disc (resp. the punctured disc) in $\mathbb C$. Let $u$ be a smooth function over the total disc $\mathbb D$ (which is not harmonic usually). I am interested in the following question:
For the fixed $u$ and a fixed rational number $q\in (0,1)$, can we always find some solution $h$
which  is smooth over $\mathbb D^*$, but may have poles along the original such that the following  equation holds
over $\mathbb D^*$?
$$\partial\bar{\partial}u=\partial\bar{\partial}h+ q \frac{dz}{z}\wedge \bar\partial h.$$
I have tried some candidates, such as let $u=\frac{h}{z}$ or something, but all are lost. If this equation cannot be solved always, I wonder that  can we give some counterexamples?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.
EDIT  I don't understand why someone closed my question before. It is surely obvious that Find a solution satisfying a $\partial\bar{\partial}$ equation on the punctured disc   doesn't acquire my demand, since we only assume that h is smooth here rather than holomorphic on the punctured disc. If one wants to close one question, have a look at the difference is necessary and basic.
As pointed by Conrad, it is equi to ask if the PDE
$\Delta h+a \frac{\partial_{\bar z}h}{z}＝f$,
has a solution $h\in C^2(D^*)$
with $a$ constant and $f＝\Delta u.$

You are effectively asking if the PDE
$$
\Delta h+ \frac{q}{4z} \partial_{\bar{z}}h=f
$$
has a smooth solution $h \in C^2(\mathbb{D}^*)$ with $\frac{1}{4}\Delta u=f$.

@F.Conrad, thanks for pointing out this. I will add the tag PDE. For this equation, have you got any ideas...？

It is an elliptic second-order equation, try to search the Evans PDE book or the one by Gilbard-Trudinger. The problem might be the coefficient $\frac{q}{4z}$ not being in $L^{\infty}$ and also not Hölder continuous or continuous across the origin. This is just from the top of my head.
The one thing, which I find off-putting for a PDE approach is that you only want a pole at the origin as well as $q$ being rational irritates me a lot. The pole-condition might be hard to guarantee by just using elliptic regularity theory.

You can always solve the equation (even for general $q\in \mathbb C$ and $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb D^*)$):
Let's conjugate the equation (and replace $\bar u$ by $u$ and $\bar h$ by $h$ again), then we need to solve:
$$
\partial \bar \partial u =\partial \bar  \partial h+ q \frac{d\bar z}{\bar z} \wedge \partial h = \partial\left(\bar \partial h +qh\frac{d\bar z}{\bar z}\right)
$$
Let $f=\bar \partial u\in \Omega^{0,1}(\mathbb D^*)$ and $\alpha = q \frac{d\bar z}{\bar z}\in \Omega^{0,1}(\mathbb D^*)$, then it's enough to solve:
$$
f = (\bar \partial +\alpha)h \tag{$\star$}
$$
The operator $\bar\partial_\alpha=\bar \partial + \alpha$ turns $\mathbb D^*\times \mathbb C$ into a holomorphic vector bundle over $\mathbb D^*$. Since $\mathbb D^*$ ist Stein (as any complex one-dimensional domain), the Oka-Grauert principle tells us that this holomorphic vector bundle is trivial. In other words: There exists a smooth function $\varphi\colon \mathbb D^*\to GL(1,\mathbb C)$ such that
$$
\bar\partial_\alpha \varphi  = 0. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Then:
$$
\bar \partial(\varphi^{-1}h)=-\varphi^{-1}\bar\partial \varphi (\varphi^{-1} h)+  \varphi^{-1} \bar \partial h = \varphi^{-1} \bar\partial_\alpha h,
$$
that is, upon setting $H=\varphi^{-1}h$ and $F=\varphi^{-1} f$, equation $(\star)$ becomes equivalent to:
$$
\bar\partial H  = F
$$
The solvability of this equation is equivalent to $H^{0,1}_{\bar \partial}(\mathbb D^*)=0$, again due to $\mathbb D^*$ being Stein.

In the simple situation at hand, you can find $\varphi$ as $\varphi= e^\psi$ as follows:
$$
(\dagger) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad\bar \partial \psi = -\alpha \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \psi = -\frac{q}{\bar z} \quad \Leftarrow \quad \psi(z) = -q\ln (z\bar z)\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \varphi(z)=|z|^{-2q}
$$

Dear @Jan Bohr, sorry for my late reply. I really appreciate the answer you provided, which is very beautiful! The idea of using the fact that for a complex line bundle $E$, it admits a holomorphic structure <=> there exists a operator $\bar\partial_E$ satisfying the Leibniz rule and integrable condition (that is your construction $\bar\partial_\alpha$) is also clever! Anyway, I learn a lot, thanks again.
